# How to increase counter as jframe as closes and new jframe is opened?

Tags: java, counter

I have 3 jframes. After user answer questions on each frame, if they succeed i need to increase the marks. The user can go to the next frame whether they succeed or fail. 
I did this by having a class called calculatemark and a setmark method in it.

```
int total =0; 
 public void setMark() {
   total++;
   System.out.println("Total :- " + total);
    }
```

which will increase the mark. so on each frame i call this method to increase the mark. The problem is as i to create an instance of the class calculatemark on each frame  the counter is not increasing as the variables get initialized as well. Can anyone please help me to let me know how to implement this? Any other ways i should do this to increase the counter? Do i really need to  have a database connection and update this? I read something about singleton? is this helpful here? Please help i am a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CalculateMark {

 int mark=0;
 public static CalculateMark calc = new CalculateMark();

    private CalculateMark() {
    }

    public static CalculateMark getInstance(){
        return calc;
    }

    public void addMark(boolean x){
    // x is true if answer is right
        if(x){
            mark+=50;

        }
         System.out.println(mark);
    }

}
```

Then say you have 3 frames Frame1, Frame2, Frame3.

on answering , just call another frame

```
  CalculateMark().getInstance().addMark(true);
  new Frame2().setVisible(true);
  this.dispose();
```

I am new in Stackoverflow , please correct me if my way of answering is not correct..

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate an `CalculateMark` instance as an instance variable in the class which opens up the JFrames.

Then, in your JFrame subclasses, make a constructor like this:

```
public MyJFrame(CalculatMark counter){

}
```

Whenever you create a new JFrame, pass in the reference to *the same* `CalculatMark` object.

Basically, just pass around a reference to this single `CalculateMark` object, and you should be good.
I don't have your code, so I'm not sure exactly how you'd do that, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Is it possible to show any example on it... sorry.. I know how to instantiate but where do i instantiate and keep the reference? Thanks in advance

Comment: @BrownSugar I have to fix my answer. Before I do, are you subclassing JFrame right now?

Comment: My jframes are called from one by another from the next button with actions performed.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works well with the singleton, as i think it is referencing the same instance that was created. no matter how many instance that i create it is actually pointing to the same one.. :)

Comment: @BrownSugar arun's method of using a singleton is better and easier to maintain. Instead of passing around this reference, you can call `CalculatMark.getInstance()` anywhere and you'll be returned that single instance of `CalculateMark`. You can google "singleton java" and get many articles explaining it.

Comment: thanks yts... i could do it with the way you showed me as well.. just trying both...